# In TinyMCE 4.x how do you attach a click event handler to content?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I have been trying many things to attach a click event handler to a selection box in tinymce 4.0.2 content with no success. Does anyone know how to do this in a custom plugin? The following is what I have tried but it is not functioning.

```
ctr++;                      
var id = 'vnetforms_elem_'+ctr;
editor.insertContent('<select id="'+id+'"><option>X</option</select>');                     
tinymce.dom.DOMUtils.bind(tinymce.activeEditor.dom.select('#'+id)[0],'click',function() {
    alert('click!');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery this may help:

```
$(ed.getBody()).find('#'+id).bind('click', function() {
    alert('click!');
});
```

Comment: Thariama, thanks for the feedback. It didn't work for the select-box but it did work for an anchor tag. I think this isn't a coding problem but a browser problem (firefox).

Comment: well, this is possible

Comment: I had a similar need for click events while I had TinyMCE's mode set to readonly, I was able to utilize click events using this above solution, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my own problem.

It turns out that this was indeed a bug in firefox. When a select element in firefox is marked as editable it doesn't fire events. I was able to resolve this with the following.

```
ctr++;                      
var id = 'vnetforms_elem_'+ctr;
editor.insertContent('<select id="'+id+'"></select>');                      
tinymce.activeEditor.dom.select('#'+id)[0].contentEditable = 'false';                       
addEvent(tinymce.activeEditor.dom.select('#'+id)[0],'click',function() {
    alert('MyClick');
});
```

Where addEvent is defined in the custom plugin as

```
var addEvent = function(node,eventName,func){

    if ("undefined" == typeof node || null == node) {              
    } else {
        if (!node.ownerDocument.addEventListener && node.ownerDocument.attachEvent) {   
            node.attachEvent('on' + eventName, func);
        } else node.addEventListener(eventName,func,false);
    }
}; this.addEvent = addEvent;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, and I am working in Chrome. Thanks mate.